# PXSubordinateSelector Using the Where

Tags: acumatica

I need information on how to use the PXSubordinateSelector attribute with the Where type that you can allegedly set on the attribute.  Does anybody know how to use this attribute?

Specifically, I need to filter the selector by a custom field in the EPCompanyTree table if possible.  Not sure what tables this selector attribute usese.  It seems to be tucked into the Acumatica black box.  Something like this:

```
 [PXSubordinateSelector(typeof(Where<EPCompanyTree.customField, Equal<{somevalue}>>))]
```

I've tried setting the Where to an arbitrary filter on the EPCompanyTree.sortorder field but, I'm getting an "is not bound" error when clicking on the lookup.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is the defined Search in the `GetCommand` method of the `PXSubordinateSelectorAttribute`. Below is the disassembled code of that method:

```
    private static Type GetCommand(Type where)
    {
        Type whereType = typeof(Where<CREmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>, Or<EPCompanyTreeMember.workGroupID, Owned<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>);
        if (where != null)
        {
            whereType = BqlCommand.Compose(new Type[]
            {
                typeof(Where2<, >),
                typeof(Where<CREmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>, Or<EPCompanyTreeMember.workGroupID, Owned<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>),
                typeof(And<>),
                where
            });
        }
        return BqlCommand.Compose(new Type[]
        {
            typeof(Search5<, , , >),
            typeof(CREmployee.bAccountID),
            typeof(LeftJoin<EPCompanyTreeMember, On<EPCompanyTreeMember.userID, Equal<CREmployee.userID>>>),
            whereType,
            typeof(Aggregate<GroupBy<CREmployee.acctCD>>)
        });
    }
```

As you can see from code the Search is being organized on `CREmployee` with left joined `EPCompanyTreeMember`, meanwhile, your code is trying to add a condition on `EPCompanyTree` field which is not participating in the Search.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.